# i18n compilation failed with Sass - Resource file not found

Tags: angular, sass

In our Angular 4 app, we are trying to use **i18n**, the problem is when we run `npm run i18n` we get an error 'Resource file not found':

> Error: Compilation failed. Resource file not found: C:/Projekte/Git/KWKPortal/App/src/app/core/menu/src/app/shared/styles/variables
>       at ModuleResolutionHostAdapter.readResource (C:\Projekte\Git\KWKPortal\App\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\compiler_host.js:387:19)
>       at CompilerHost.loadResource (C:\Projekte\Git\KWKPortal\App\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\compiler_host.js:251:29)
>       at Object.get (C:\Projekte\Git\KWKPortal\App\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:27273:103)
>       at DirectiveNormalizer._fetch (C:\Projekte\Git\KWKPortal\App\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:14095:43)
>       at C:\Projekte\Git\KWKPortal\App\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:14211:68
>       at Array.map (native)
>       at DirectiveNormalizer._loadMissingExternalStylesheets (C:\Projekte\Git\KWKPortal\App\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:14211:14)
>       at C:\Projekte\Git\KWKPortal\App\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:14214:26
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
>       at Module.runMain (module.js:606:11)
>   Extraction failed

That is how I import the `variables.scss`:

`@import "src/app/shared/styles/variables";`

I also tried with `.scss` and it didn't work.

That is my folder structure:

[image]

And here is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "i18n": "ng-xi18n"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.1.3",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "^1.0.10",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "^1.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-layout": "^1.0.3",
    "@progress/kendo-theme-default": "^2.37.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.2.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: where do you import variables.scss ? file and its path ?

Comment: please post your package.json also

Comment: Thanks. I updated my question with my folder structure and my package.json. ´ng build´ is working properly...

Comment: npm install @angular/{common,compiler,compiler-cli,core,forms,http,platform-browser,platform-browser-dynamic,platform-server,router}@latest typescript@latest --save

just run this command and try again

Comment: I've got an error:

 + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingArgument

Comment: when do you get this error ?

Comment: please try with @import "../../shared/styles/variables";

Comment: for some reason i got the "opposit" error:
I was name the scss files in the proper way (with underscores)

When importing but when importing then without underscore and fileending, i got the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**For Sass - Resource file not found**

change your path to :

```
@import "../../shared/styles/variables";
```

and file name :

`variables.scss` to `_variables.scss`

> The underscore lets Sass know that the file is only a partial file and
>   that it should not be generated into a CSS file. Sass partials are
>   used with the @import directive.

---

**For `toLowerCase` error :**

add `--i18nFormat=xlf` in `package.json`

```
"i18n": "ng-xi18n --i18nFormat=xlf"
```

Comment: looks better now, but I still have the following error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of null`. Do you know what it is? Nevertheless I'll set this as the correct answer. Unfortunatelly I had to explicitly use the extension **.scss**. Thanks

Comment: no :( I have already tried this, I found this link: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16235 and I'm just about to post there to ask

Comment: okay try to add that in your "i18n": "ng-xi18n  --i18nFormat=xlf"

Comment: and then run : npm run i18n

Comment: YES! Thanks...I got the file generated now

Comment: great , :) . I just solved all these errors today in my current project , it took my whole day.